# Inline TextFormField in Stepper

Tags: android, forms, flutter, dart, stepper

I have to put two TextFormField near but when I create Row and in childrens put the two TextFormField, the container that contain the Stepper disappear. How can I do it?

Code that make Container disappear

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Form(
        key: global.formStateKeys[formIndex],
        child: Column(
            children: <Widget> [
                Row(
                    children: <Widget> [
                        TextFormField(),
                        TextFormField()
                    ],
                )
            ]
        )
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you got en error in your console. You should check for details. To solve your problem try wrap TextFormField with Expanded.

```
Expanded(child: TextFormField()),
Expanded(child: TextFormField()),
```